# Gensim's similarity: how does it work?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I wonder how the [similarity](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html) works with gensim ? How the different shards are created and does it increase performance when looking only for top-N similar document ? More generally, is there a documentation about the internal structures of gensim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the internals of gensim is the full source code:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim

With high-dimensional data like this, finding the *exact* top-N most-similar vectors generally requires an exhaustive search against all candidates. That is, there's no simple sharding that allows most vectors to be ignored as too-far away and still gives precise results.

There *are* approximate indexing techniques, like [ANNOY](https://github.com/spotify/annoy), that can speed searches... but they tend to miss some of the true top-N results. Gensim includes a [demo notebook of using ANNOY-indexing with gensim's word2vec support](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/annoytutorial.ipynb). (It should be possible to do something similar with other text-vectors, like the bag-of-words representations in the tutorial you link.)

Comment: Thank for the clarity and the ANNOY suggestion.